# Firebase: retrieve data from realtime database as an Int

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i've been using firebase to retrieve the test data from the firebase database and set the value to a label but the problem i am having is that i want to retrieve the data as an Int instead of the String.

```
  func retData(){
    rootRef.child("users").child("Test").observeEventType(.Value){
        (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        self.simpleLabel.text = snap.value?.description

    }    }
```

Comment: if data in database is String than its retrieve as a String ...

Comment: El Captain probably has it right. It'll easiest to see if you post the relevant snippet of your JSON structure from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase represents data as JSON strings, and can only be retrieved as such. I ran into a similar issue on a recent project & had to resort to int>string for pushing data to FB, and string>int on the string retrieved from FB.No code submitted for the question, but basically you have to cast the int to a string using constructor syntax as:

let myStr = String(myInt)
//push the string up to Firebase

......

//pull the string back from Firebase

let myInt =Int(myStr)